# rails 3 iterate through model with date range and group_by day

Tags: ruby, iterator, group-by, ruby-on-rails-3.1, where-clause

I have a model called `Dish` which is `:served_from` and `:served_until` a day, e.g. spaghetti bolognese is served from Monday 2011-10-31 until Sunday 2011-11-06.

On the restaurant show page I want to display all dishes available during cweek 44:

- Monday: spaghetti bolognese
- Tuesday: spaghetti bolognese
- ...

Until now I only stored `:date` in `Dish` and used the following code to group all dishes of the current cweek by day:

```
dishes = Dish.where(:date => (Date.commercial(Date.today.year, Date.today.cweek, 1))..(Date.commercial(Date.today.year, Date.today.cweek, 7)))
dishes.group_by(&:date).each do |date, dish|
  puts "Date: #{date}"
  puts "Dishes: #{dish.count}"
  dish.each do |dish|
    puts dish.name
  end
end
```

I replaced `:date` with `:served_from` and `:served_until` to handle dishes which are served more often then one day. But how do I use `Dish.where` to find all dishes between `:served_from` and `:served_until` and group them by cweek.day?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when you creating dish add to database more than one record, for example:

```
title: spaghetti bolognese
served_from: 2011-10-29
served_until: 2011-10-31
```

and add to database is not a

```
{title: "spaghetti bolognese", served_from: "2011-10-29", served_from: "2011-10-31"}
```

but

```
[{title: "spaghetti bolognese", date: "2011-10-29"}, {title: "spaghetti bolognese", date: "2011-10-30"},{title: "spaghetti bolognese", date: "2011-10-31"}]
```

It's not so pretty way, but it's solution.